# How to add partition in presto?

Tags: hive, presto

In hive I can do it by:

> ALTER TABLE xxx ADD PARTITION
>   (datehour='yy')  LOCATION
>   'zz';

How can I do it in presto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, Presto Hive connector does not provide means for creating new partitions at arbitrary locations. If your partition location is under table location, you can use [Presto Hive connector procedures](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#procedures):

- `system.create_empty_partition` -- creates a new empty partition with specified values for partition keys
- `system.sync_partition_metadata` -- synchronizes partition list in Metastore with the partitions on the storage

If you want to create/declare partitions somewhere else than under table's location, please [file an issue](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues).